# Term for common or accepted usage of how a language is used

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning-in-context, synonyms

I'm trying to recall a word I've used before and I'm coming up blank. Here is the context: in computer programming, we often have new languages with multiple ways to accomplish the same end result. After a language is used for a while, people generally start to agree on the most "accepted" or common way of doing something. The term I am looking for describes the common or accepted usage of such a language.

This might be similar to *colloquial*, but that implies a less formal usage. *Canonical* might also be similar, but that also implies correct usage, not accepted usage.

To use in a sentence, "I'm familiar with the new language XYZ and all of its new syntax, but I'm interested in in the ___________ usage."

Try as I might, I just can't pick out the word I'm looking for, and Internet searches just come up with the same list of "almost" words.

Comment: The usual term is *standard* -- it's not very precise, but then neither is what it names.

Comment: [Pythonic](https://blog.startifact.com/posts/older/what-is-pythonic.html) - but that works only for one particular language. Actually, that website mentions *idiomatic* which might work for you.

Comment: *Canonical* can also be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe *[idiomatic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idiomatic)* is the word you're looking for.

> 1. ... conforming to the usual manner of expression in a language
>      <sub>*(from Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary via [TheFreeDictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/idiomatic))*</sub>
> 2. peculiar to a particular group, individual, or style
>      <sub>*(from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idiomatic))*</sub>

Comment: Yes, yes, yes!!! I have been struggling with writers block over that for days.

Comment: @Edwinashworth A much more appropriate definition, thanks.  I will edit that in.

Answer (score 0):

*Common* and *accepted* both seem apropos ...

How about ***established***?

OD:

> [***established***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/established):
>   Having been in existence for a long time and therefore recognized and
>   generally accepted.
>
> Example: *‘Why this was not an already **established** practice is a
>   mystery to critics.’*

The meaning of "for a ling time" is relative.

Your example:

> "I'm familiar with the new language XYZ and all of its new syntax, but
>   I'm interested in the established usage."